# Static block position

Tags: magento, position

I have an image slider on my main page directly put into the homepage, then I have a static block that shows some content and I put it into the content area (mid column). It appears above the image slider but I want to have it below. Currently I use this code:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="cms/block" name="newproduct">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>newproduct</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

I tried it with the before and after attribute in my layout but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried after="-" use this and check it

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="cms/block" name="newproduct" after="-">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>newproduct</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

OR

go to cms -> homepage->content

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="newproduct"}}
```

is there any content in home page cms page then add above code at the end.

Comment: refresh cache and cache storage then check

Comment: Have you added <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('newproduct') ?> in home page ? if you have added this then change this code position after all content where you want to add.

Comment: where do i have to add this?

Comment: I have edited my answer second way to put your static block check it.

Comment: well it worked, but this results in a bug that happened before. my static block is a product list, and if i add it to the home page directly, it has those "list dots", i tried to remove them via css but it didnt work. that's why i want to have the block not attached to the home page, but rather as a custom block put below

Answer (score 0):

```
    <p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{skin url=''}}js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
/* index slider */
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#s4')
.before('<div id="nav_slides"><div id="nav_sl_wrap"></div></div>')
.cycle({
    fx:     'fade',
    speed:  '1000',
    timeout: 8000,
    pager:  '#nav_sl_wrap'
});
});
// ]]></script>
</p>
<div class="index_slider">
<div id="s4">
<div class="cl1"><img alt="" src="{{skin url=''}}images/slider_pic1.jpg" /></div>
<div class="cl2"><img alt="" src="{{skin url=''}}images/slider_pic2.jpg" /></div>
<div class="cl3"><img alt="" src="{{skin url=''}}images/slider_pic3.jpg" /></div>
<div class="cl4"><img alt="" src="{{skin url=''}}images/slider_pic4.jpg" /></div>
</div>
</div>
```

thats the slider, and i cannot put your code below because it wont recognize it as code